# SQL Server visual tool

Tags: sql-server

I recently moved to the MS environment where we use SQL Server.

I'm struggling to find a tool which would allow updating tables by clicking on the result view (e.g. from a `SELECT` statement) and modifying the data directly there rather then writing an `UPDATE` statement.

Could you suggest a tool?

Reasoning: it takes ages to write `UPDATE` statements, especially if you join multiple tables.

Comment: Well SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) it self an IDE with tons of tools in it.

Comment: Learn SQL! The visual tools are always just "wrappers" or add-ons to the actual SQL being generated. Or find a tool that will generate the SQL skeleton for you. But using SQL is the best solution in the end.

Comment: My own impression is this: SQL Server Management Studio is a tool for managing, primarily, server instances, databases, schemas, tables, users etc., but *not* the data. It's *SQL* (i.e. the language) that is about managing data, and with respect to that, it is SSMS's virtually only job to provide you with a way to issue your SQL queries, as well as to get the feedback. If you want interactivity editing (arbitrary) data, use a third party tool (or write your own). Although for tiny tables (up to 200 rows), @Greg's suggestion would probably do.

Comment: @AndriyM, I agree with you completely. As I mentioned, I don't recommend using the Edit Top 200 Rows. SQL Commands are the best way to manage the data. But TECHNICALLY you can edit all of the rows on your table. Once you choose edit top 200, you can then edit the sql and remove the "TOP 200". Just documenting for completeness, not recommending it

Comment: @marc_s Your comment is misfired as I never said I don't know how to do it. I just want a 21st century way to do it. The clock on your desktop is a wrapper too. When you change your time do you go to the console and update it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't use it (or recommend it), but it is built into SQL Management Studio, just right click on the table:

[image]

Comment: There's also a SQL design mode in there which lets you drag and drop objects to join together like in Access. Use at your own risk

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Management Studio. Create a new View and right-click on it and choose Modify. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx